# How to create a CNAME alias with Google Domains

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the steps on the Google Cloud Platform's [Hosting a Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). The first step is to create a CNAME alias that points to `c.storage.googleapis.com`. How to do this depends on which domain registration service you use.

In my case, I got the domain (peek.solutions) on Goolge Domains itself:

[image]

However, I can't find Google Domains itself among the [host-specific steps](https://support.google.com/a/topic/1615038) given by Google. How can I create the CNAME alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the icon in the DNS column.

In the following page, there is a section with the heading "Custom resource records."

You will see a drop down menu there where "A" is the default but you can select "CNAME" to create that type of record.